# Where does angular two-way binding is useful?

Tags: angularjs

two-way binding feature in angular is so popular, and according to angular community it is good when compared with one-way binding.

And there are lots of simple examples to explain how it works.

But my question is where does we use that feature in real applications.
 - One example is using with input boxes, other than that is there any good uses of it?

Answer (score 2):

Two way binding as a default wasn't wise because it creates perf issues (~2000 watchers and your app can go bad fast). It led to the introduction of {{::}} binding syntax (bind once syntax) in Angular 1. Overall I can't see where I agree that default two way binding is said to be a good thing by any knowledgeable Angular dev.

I can tell you for a fact, having written an application that displayed many lists of different kinds of objects simultaneously, that default two way binding was a mistake. It created far too many persistent watchers. The community overall seems to strongly agree.

So what you suggest here is correct; there are uses for two way binding. But those needs should be seen as few and far between. And even then, you could probably get around the need for it at all with a little thinking.

For me, two way binding is primarily useful for input fields. But the mechanism is most definitely downplayed now, it should be used sparingly.

Comment: Yes, completely agree with you!!,  it is useful in few scenarios but most of the times we'd prefer one-way binding with REST/some_JSON_service to implement decoupled client-server apps. But how could it be main and bold feature in angular. :)

Comment: _"~2000 watchers and your app can go bad fast"_ True, but how does that relate to two-way binding? And what do you mean by _"Two way binding as a default"_? An old-style Angular app will have more one-way bindings than two-way-ones. A component-based app even more so.

Comment: Angular 1 doc for one-time binding (introduced 1.3 I think):

The main purpose of one-time binding is to create a binding that gets deregistered and frees up resources once the binding is stabilized. Reducing the number of expressions being watched makes the digest loop faster and allows more information to be displayed at the same time.

Before {{::}} syntax, every time you used {{myvar}}, that expression would be evaluated (via watch) every digest. In a view rendering hundreds or thousands of objects, all using default binding, that created huge problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you bind a **label** with a `$scope` variable, though the binding is two-way (by definition) it is only relevant in the direction JS -> HTML.

A two-way binding is only fully exploited in cases where the value can also be changed by the user, meaning any type of INPUT component (textbox, dropdown, checkbox, etc.).

One trivial (though one-directional) example is when you have a page that can be displayed in many languages. You would deploy `$scope` variable all over, and assign to them strings in the current language.

When the user switches language, the simple assignment of the new strings to the corresponding variable will yield the screen to be automatically update to the new language.

Comment: Thanks!, So two-way binding is mostly useful in user changeable elements  ? but not in plain html elements bind with model object.

Comment: It is exactly the same concept (and functionality), except that with (for instance) labels, the HTML -> JS direction cannot be expressed (since you - the user - cannot change the string of a **label** element).

Comment: By the way, if my answer complies with your expectations, you may wish to consider marking it as such (i.e. clicking on the "V").